Can 茸 in 毛茸茸 (máo​róng​róng) be pronounced rōng?
YouDao gives this:

毛茸茸 / máo rōng rōng /

CC-CEDICT gives this:

毛茸茸 máo​róng​róng​

Yabla lists both pronunciations, while my 《现代汉语词典》 only contains 毛茸茸 máo​róng​róng and 茸​ róng (in fact, it lists nothing pronounced rōng).
These are inconsistent, so...
Question: Can 茸 in 毛茸茸 (máo​róng​róng) be pronounced rōng?
Maybe these other resources are mistaken, or maybe there's some dialect thing going on here.

國語辭典 :

1 茸    ㄖㄨㄥˊ (róng) - 鹿茸; 毛茸茸

2 茸    ㄖㄨㄥˇ (rǒng) - 丰茸; 蓊茸


毛茸茸 / máo rōng rōng / - I think certain people/region pronounces this way on admirable furry lovely things, "
這大衣毛茸茸的,看來好暖好舒適啊!"; "這小鴨子毛茸茸的,好可愛啊!"
https://www.zdic.net/hans/%E8%93%8A%E8%8C%B8 (汉典)

This article explains the underlying tone sandhi pattern that creates two versions of tones in ABB words, including 毛茸茸.

但是在ABB的词语中，黄澄澄 huáng dēng dēng，红彤彤 hóng tōng tōng，绿油油 lǜ yōu yōu 会产生音变。一般变作一声…


但是ABB的音变，是在北京语音基础上的普通话音变习惯，并不是铁律。关于ABB叠词的音变规律，语言界争议颇多。

This tone sandhi does not strictly apply to every ABB word. For instance, in 毛茸茸, the character 茸 is most commonly pronounced róng, without a tone change.

My suggestion is máo róng róng.
See how news announcers say about ABB pronunciation, 康辉 mentioned in a live show in 2020. At least 白茫茫 is now officially treated as bái máng máng instead of bái māng māng. video material

It can only be pronounced rōng in 毛茸茸.
The standard pronunciation is máoróngróng- máorōngrōng is a colloquial variant.

Actually, its original pronunciation is ​róng and rǒng, but rōng could be accepted in some region, and some couldn't. For Taiwan, we don't pronounce it as rōng but ​róng.

There's a not-very-well-known sandhi-like phenomenon ("Tone 2 becomes higher and changes its direction, approaching the tone 1 pitch contour, when put between tone 1 or 2 and any other full tone"). This phenomenon occurs in conversational speech. It is described in the Wikipedia article on Chinese Phonology. Mao2rong2rong2 fits the criteria for this phenomenon.
I believe this could well explain why some references give tone 1 in the middle of this term. Of course this doesn't explain the tone 1 given at the end of the term.

No, but máo róng rōng would be the practical one.
You know, in practice, tones will change in oral speech.
